# VC++ allows to use const types for STL containers. Why?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stl, constants, visual-c++-2008

STL containers require the stored values to be copy constructible and assignable. const T is obviously not an assignable type for any T, but I tried to use it (just being curious) and found out that it compiles and, moreover, behaves as an assignable type.

```
vector<const int> v(1);
v[0] = 17;
```

This successfully runs in Visual Studio 2008 and assigns v[0] to 17.

Comment: Not only that--VS 2010 allows you to *assign new values* to `v[0]`. Try it!

Comment: I'm curious what VC gives for typeid(vector<const int>::value_type).name() (and either compare it to typeid(vector<int>::value_type).name() or demangle it).

Comment: One and the same: `int`.

Comment: The vector<T>::value_type in VC's standard library implementation comes via allocator<T>::value_type which has a partial specialization for const T that simply removes the const: `template<class _Ty> struct _Allocator_base<const _Ty>{ typedef _Ty value_type;};`

Answer (score 12):

This is not a bug in the implementation as others have suggested.

Violating the requirements of a C++ Standard Library facility does not render your program ill-formed, it yields undefined behavior.

You have violated the requirement that the value type stored in a container must be copy constructible and assignable (`const` types are not assignable, obviously), so your program exhibits undefined behavior.

The applicable language from the C++ Standard can be found in C++03 17.4.3.6 [lib.res.on.functions]:

> In certain cases (replacement functions, handler functions, operations on types used to instantiate standard library  template  components),  the  C++  Standard  Library  depends  on  components  supplied  by  a  C++  program.  If  these  components  do  not  meet  their  requirements,  the  Standard  places  no  requirements  on  the implementation.
>
> In particular, the effects are undefined in the following cases:
>
> ...
>
> - for types used as template arguments when instantiating a template component, if the operations on the type  do  not  implement  the  semantics  of  the  applicable Requirements subclause.

The Visual C++ Standard Library implementation may do anything with this code, including silently removing or ignoring the const-qualification, and it is still standards-conforming.

Comment: In my humblest of opinions, the silent qualification removal here is really, really ugly.

Comment: The qualification removal may actually break perverse but still standards conforming code.  You could write a class that has a const-qualified copy assignment operator that ensures `t == u` after `t = u` _and_ a non-const-qualified copy assignment operator that doesn't guarantee that postcondition.  This way, `const T` would be assignable, but `T` would not be.  I cannot imagine any valid use case for this, and if I saw code like that I'd probably cry.

Comment: As the standard defines "assignable", it seems that the post-condition is that t and u are equivalent. - BTW, is C++0x going to remove the assignability requirement? I can't see it in the draft any more, and it would make sense that operations not requiring assigning would work.

Comment: @UncleBens: In C++0x the Assignable and CopyConstructible concept requirements have been replaced by a set of concepts including MoveInsertable, CopyInsertable, and EmplaceConstructible, and the requirements no longer apply to the container as a whole, they apply to individual operations on the container (since some operations can only work if objects are copyable but others will work if they are only moveable).

Answer (score 1):

<s>This simply shouldn't work. At §23.1 ¶ 3 it's specified, as you said, that objects stored in a container must be `CopyConstructible` (as specified at §20.1.3) and `Assignable`.</s>

The `Assignable` requirements for a type `T` are that, being `t` and `u` of type `T`, you can do:

```
t = u
```

having a `T&` as return value and `t` equivalent to `u` as postcondition. (§23.1 ¶4)

Thus, `const` types are clearly not `Assignable`, since doing `t = u` would raise a compilation error (§7.1.5.1 ¶5).

I suppose that this is a bug in Microsoft implementation. g++ on Linux emits the typical 25 kajillion-lines template error if you even try to instantiate a `vector<const int>` (tested both with and without the `-std=c++0x` flag, just in case).

By the way, this is also explained in detail in this [IBM FAQ](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21162689).

---

In theory, as @James McNellis said, the compiler is not required to blow up on the vector instantiation (if it's undefined behavior anything can happen - including everything working fine); however, on the assignation statement there's a violation of the standard that should produce a compilation error.

In facts, the `operator[]` member returns a `vector<const int>::reference`; that one is required to be an lvalue of `T` (§23.1 ¶5 table 66); since `T` is of a `const` type, it will be a `const` lvalue. So we fall down to (§7.1.5.1 ¶5), which defines code that tries to perform an assignment to a `const` element as "ill-formed", and this demands a compilation error or at least a warning, because assignment-to-`const` is a diagnosable rule (§1.4 ¶1-2) (no "no diagnostic is required" statement is specified).

---

***Final edit***

Actually, @James McNellis is right; once you've invoked undefined behavior by instantiating `vector<const int>`, the usual rules stop having value, so the implementation is still standard-conforming whatever it does - including removing the `const` from the element type or generating the usual nasal demons.

Comment: An easier way to make it work would be a remove_const type trait (this exact trait should be in 0x, but maybe under a different name) rather than mutable.

Comment: @Fred Nurk: most probably it's like you said. Actually I think that the `mutable` thing I wrote was a brainfart, since `mutable` is put on non-`const` (§7.1.2 ¶8) class fields to let them be modified by `const` methods, and this has nothing to do with removing the `const` from template types.

Comment: This is not a bug in the implementation.  The OP's program exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: @James McNellis: correct, the `vector` instantiation is UB and do not demand an error, but the assignment to `const` reference does.

Comment: @Matteo:  No, it doesn't.  There are _no requirements whatsoever_ on the behavior of `vector` if you instantiate it with a type that does not meet the copy constructible and assignable requirements.

Comment: @James McNellis: hmm, this makes sense, once you've invoked UB the standard rules don't have value anymore. I stand corrected, +1 for you.